# GCP Alerting policy: Increase by 50% on dataflow elapsed time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-alerts

Currently I am trying to setup a Alert policy in GCP where I want to compare the current elapsed time of my dataflow job with the elapsed time of the previous dataflow job and fire an alert if the current job has a 50% bigger elapsed time.
Is it possible to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create alerting policies based on metric absence and metric threshold conditions. You can take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions#top_of_page) for types of alerting policies you can create. It seems the feature you are looking for is not currently supported. However, you can report for Feature request using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#top_of_page)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a rate of change condition.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions#metric-threshold

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for, but it should let you get alerts on big changes between runs.